# datetime shows extra day

Tags: php, datetime

I'm using this code to calculate days, months etc between 2 dates

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-12-01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2014-08-01');

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$year = $interval->format('%y');
$month = $interval->format('%m');
$day = $interval->format('%d');

var_dump($interval->days, $year, $month, $day);
```

The output I get is:

```
int(243) 
string(1) "0" 
string(1) "8" 
string(1) "1"
```

Why is there ONE day extra? to me it seems it's just 8 months ?

```
2014-01-01 - 2014-09-01 //8 months 0 days..
2014-04-01 - 2014-12-01 //7 months 30 days...
```

Comment: `upper_limit - lower_limit + 1` is the general formula

Comment: `2014-01-01` - `2014-09-01` = 8 months __0__ days.. `2014-04-01` - `2014-12-01` = 7 months 30 days...

Comment: I am trying this code on phpcodepad.com, and it is not giving one day extra.

Comment: Interesting, phpcodepad is PHP 5.3.23. We're using 5.4.21

Comment: 'Fence post' issue: count the posts, not the spaces in-between.  I'm guessing they didn't want to return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[From the document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)**, that's expected.

> Note: The DateInterval::format() method does not recalculate carry
>   over points in time strings nor in date segments. This is expected
>   because it is not possible to overflow values like "32 days" which
>   could be interpreted as anything from "1 month and 4 days" to "1 month
>   and 1 day".